# Bigquery "FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF" feature guarantee for data recovery

Tags: google-bigquery

In Google BigQuery, it is possible to retrieve rows of a table (snapshot) in the past (at least in the last 7 days) :

With Legacy SQL, we can use [snapshot decorators](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/table-decorators#snapshot_decorators) :

```sql
#legacySQL
SELECT * FROM [PROJECT_ID:DATASET.TABLE@-3600000]
```

With Standard SQL, we can use [`FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF` in `FROM` clause](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#from-clause) :

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT *
FROM `PROJECT_ID.DATASET.TABLE`
  FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR);
```

Both examples return snapshots of `PROJECT_ID.DATASET.TABLE` one hour ago.

But I'm wondering if there is any guarantee of retrieving table data in the past.
A colleague told me that he read somewhere (but he can't find it anymore) that this was a "best effort" feature, so potentially there may be some missing data.

Is this feature usable in production environments for data recovery (for example if someone inadvertently truncates an important table), as long as the recovery in done within the 7 days after the mistake? Is there any guarantee that we can access **the whole data** stored at a particular time?

**Update**

As @Pentium10 correctly pointed out in a comment, recovering old data after doing `CREATE OR REPLACE` jobs on a table is not possible. After some tries, I will even add that executing jobs with one of these [statement types](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/auditlogs/rest/Shared.Types/QueryStatementType) :

- `CREATE_TABLE` (`CREATE OR REPLACE`)
- `CREATE_TABLE_AS_SELECT`
- `DROP_TABLE`

completely removes the ability to retrieve data back in time for that particular table.

But, supposing that we only use the following statement types to modify the table data :

- `INSERT`
- `UPDATE`
- `DELETE`
- `MERGE`

Is there a guarantee that the snapshot data at *t* is **exactly** the data contained in the table at *t*? Or is this a "best effort" feature?

Comment: No! We personally had a trouble with this, as this syntax doesn't recover if the table is recreated using a query. We ran a CREATE OR REPLACE table syntax and no timetravel was possible to recover.

Comment: @Pentium10 Thanks for your comment. Indeed, `CREATE OR REPLACE` jobs updates the table creation date as it if were a "new" table, and so removes the ability to go back in time. I've updated my question accordingly. My question is more about other statements (`INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, `MERGE`) and the ability to retrieve the **whole data** (is there a guarantee on this feature?).

Comment: One more case is, when your dataset is removed/recreated, you also lose the ability to look back in time.

Comment: May want to edit your answer as a CTAS from a past snapshot e.g. to replace is now possible regardless how the table was created.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF` syntax is useful for querying a table at multiple points in time, but I recommend using the BigQuery CLI copy command with the `@<time>` decorator when you need to recover or roll back a table. (See the CLI example [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-tables#restoring_a_deleted_table) for a complete reference.) To do this, first determine the target recovery time in epoch milliseconds. Next, run the copy command from your local machine or the Google Cloud Shell; append the epoch time to the table name as follows.

```
bq cp test_data_set.weather_data@1588643412000 test_data_set.recovered_weather_data
```

Note that you cannot directly recover the table in place - you will need to copy the snapshot to a different table name and then copy back to the original table.

```
bq cp test_data_set.recovered_weather_data test_data_set.weather_data
```

The advantage of using the BigQuery CLI over running a query with `FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF` is that it can recover or roll back a table even in case of schema changes or deletion. The copy command will work for any timestamp when the table existed, going back seven days. (The recovery window for deleted tables used to be two days, but it was extended recently.)

Regarding recovery SLA, it's helpful to understand the architecture of BigQuery. Column data blocks are stored as objects in the Colossus File System (Google Cloud Storage), and BigQuery executes updates with a copy on write strategy. In practice, this means that no backup process is required - BigQuery simply keeps old column data blocks and metadata (thus, table versions) around until they are garbage collected. BigQuery triggers the garbage collection process seven days after an update or deletion.

As mentioned above, rollback and recovery is advertised as a core capability of BigQuery. (See, for example, the heading *Automatic backup and easy restore* on the [BigQuery landing page](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery).) Thus, it appears to be subject to the standard service level agreement for other BigQuery features.

Answer (score 0):

Bigquery saves snapshots referring to older historical versions of the defined table. Therefore, as documented, you should have no problem recovering the data that was modified.

As @Pentium10 pointed out, you can't recover a deleted table when you have already created a new table with the same name, because of that you can't recover a table after doing "**CREATE OR REPLACE**" [1].

Snapshot decorator has the limitation that a snapshot can be restored within the last 7 days and has to be bigger or equal to the time of the table creation [2], so if the table was created recently by "**CREATE OR REPLACE**" or "**CREATE**" you can't select a timestamp before the table creation.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-tables#undeletetable

[2] https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/table-decorators#snapshot-syntax

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know if there is any SLA on this feature? I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: There is no SLA in this kind of features. If you want to see the current Bigquery SLA you can see it in this link [1].

Please, if you consider this answer to be a good one, approve it.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sla

Comment: @OscarR By SLA I meant that : there is a guarantee that we can recover data in the past (as long as we don't run `CREATE OR REPLACE` queries, or delete the table/dataset, as stated in the comments section of the question). Since this is not an Alpha or Beta feature, and this is not excluded from the SLA in the docs, I believe the SLA for the whole BigQuery product applies. Can you please confirm this? This is the only information missing for the answer to be accepted.

Comment: I'd like to know if this way to restore old data is reliable on production environments.

Comment: If you want to be sure that your data will still in your table even if it's modified in a production environment, I recommend that you use other type of solution.
For example, backups every day of your data such as other tables or Google Cloud Storage files, this way you will have more guarantees to keep your data.