# How to recreate old snapshot using field history table in Bigquery

Tags: database, google-bigquery, data-cleaning, business-intelligence

I'm currently working on an interesting problem. I am trying to recreate state of table as it was on a given previous date. I have 2 tables

1. Table A: consists of live data, gets refreshed on an hourly basis.
2. Table A_field_history: consists of changes made to the fields in Table A.

Following image consists of current state, where Table A has live updated data and Table A_field_history only captures changes made to the fields on table A.
[image: Basic Structure of Table A and Table A_field_history]

I am trying to recreate Table A as of particular given date. Following image consists of table state as it was on 06/30/2020.
The requirement is to have capability to recreate state of Table A based on any given date.
[image: Table A as of previous given date]

Comment: Did you know you can travel back in time on a table in BigQuery using native functions? You can go back as far as 7 days. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59048115/bigquery-for-system-time-as-of-feature-guarantee-for-data-recovery

Comment: Thanks Graham, I was not knowing this. But I am looking at a wider time frame, like 6month, 12 months etc.

Comment: So what you want is to perform all the updates backwards until the specified date?

Comment: I just found a solution, posted same below. Thanks for checking in!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually identified a way to rollback (virtually, not on actual table) all the updates made after given specific date. Following are the steps followed:

Create dummy tables:

```
WITH
Table_A AS
(
SELECT 1 As ID, '2020-6-28' as created_date, 10 as qty, 100 as value
Union ALL
SELECT 2 As ID, '2020-5-29' as created_date, 20 as qty, 200 as value),

Table_A_field_history AS
(
SELECT 'xyz' id,'2020-07-29'    created_date,'12345'    created_by,'qty'    field,'10'  new_value,'200' old_value,'1'   A_id
UNION ALL
SELECT 'abc' id,'2020-07-24'    created_date,'12345'    created_by,'qty'    field,'20'  new_value,'10' old_value,'2'    A_id
UNION ALL
SELECT 'xyz' id,'2020-07-29'    created_date,'12345'    created_by,'value'  field,'100' new_value,'2000' old_value,'1'  A_id
UNION ALL
SELECT 'abc' id,'2020-07-24'    created_date,'12345'    created_by,'value'  field,'200' new_value,'5000' old_value,'2'  A_id
UNION ALL

SELECT 'xyz' id,'2020-06-29'    created_date,'12345'    created_by,'qty'    field,'200' new_value,'' old_value,'1'  A_id
UNION ALL
SELECT 'abc' id,'2020-05-30'    created_date,'12345'    created_by,'qty'    field,'10'  new_value,'' old_value,'2'  A_id
UNION ALL
SELECT 'xyz' id,'2020-06-29'    created_date,'12345'    created_by,'value'  field,'2000'    new_value,'' old_value,'1'  A_id
UNION ALL
SELECT 'abc' id,'2020-05-30'    created_date,'12345'    created_by,'value'  field,'5000'    new_value,'' old_value,'2'  A_id

),
```

Step 1. Create date cte to filter data based on given date:

```
`date_spine 
AS

(
SELECT * FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2020-01-01', CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 Day)) AS as_of_date 
),`
```

Step 2. Above created date cte can be used as a Spine for our query, cross join to map `as_of_date` with all the changes made in the history table.

```
    date_changes
AS
(
SELECT DISTINCT
date.as_of_date,
hist.A_id 
FROM Table_A_field_history hist CROSS JOIN date_spine date
),
```

Step 3. Now we have `as_of_date` mapped to all historical transactions, now we can get max of change date.

```
most_recent_changes AS (
  SELECT
    dc.as_of_date,
    dc.A_id ,
    MAX(fh.created_date) AS created_date,
  FROM date_changes dc
  LEFT JOIN Table_A_field_history AS fh
    ON dc.A_id   = fh.A_id  
  WHERE CAST(fh.created_date AS DATE) <= dc.as_of_date
  GROUP BY  dc.as_of_date,
    dc.A_id 
),
```

Step 4. Now mapping max change date with actual `created_date` and history table

```
past_changes AS (
  SELECT
    mr.as_of_date,
    mr.A_id,
    mr.created_date,
    a.id AS entry_id,
    a.created_by AS created_by_id,
    CASE WHEN a.field='qty' THEN a.new_value ELSE '' END AS qty,
    CASE WHEN a.field='value' THEN a.new_value ELSE '' END AS value,
  FROM most_recent_changes AS mr
  LEFT JOIN Table_A_field_history AS a
    ON mr.A_id  = a.A_id 
    AND mr.created_date = a.created_date
  WHERE a.id IS NOT NULL
)
```

Step 5. Now we can use `as_of_date` to get historical state of Table A.

```
Select *
From past_changes x
WHERE x.as_of_date = '2020-07-29'
```