# Recover a deleted table with flexible columns

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, recovery

I accidentaly deleted a table which had "flexible columns" there were column names that had spaces between them, now that I want to retrieve it in the terminal I get the error

"Error processing job 'job_jobID': Table mytable@1690351200000 with flexible column name `Column WithSpaces Name` does not support table copy.

Thank you in advance to anyone who can help me

The command line I'm referring to is mentioned in this post

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59048115/bigquery-for-system-time-as-of-feature-guarantee-for-data-recovery](https://stackoverflow.com)

Looks like this:

```
bq cp test_data_set.weather_data@1588643412000 test_data_set.recovered_weather_data
```

I've also tried doing extract but it doesn't seems to work for recovering files

Comment: try time travel then use "save as a differnt bq table that you can rename if needed.  https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/time-travel

Comment: here is an example query for time travel:  SELECT *
FROM `your-project.your-dataset.your-table`
FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 75 MINUTE)

Comment: Thank you, I tried this option but I get "Not found: Table projecid:dataset.table@1690213468855 was not found in location us-east1"

Comment: It's often the case with the preview feature, that's why it's not recommended for production or critical use case.